# JPA CascadeType.ALL is not deleting children orphan records

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

I am working on a pet project using Spring Boot (latest version 1.5.4) with Hibernate and came across an issue which could not figure out myself.

I am trying to create a OneToMany relation between Posts and Comments.

Parent Class:

```
    @NotNull
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "parentPost") 
private Set<Comment> commentList;
```

Child class:

```
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="parent_id")
    @JsonBackReference
    private Post parentPost;
```

For some reason CascadeType.ALL does not cascade on DELETE and does not remove orphan comment records. However, if I change CascadeType.ALL to CascadeType.REMOVE everything will work fine and those records get deleted when parent Post gets deleted.

Does anyone know why am I getting this behaviour? is it a bug or something wrong in my code?

Answer (score 0):

Probably a statement-order fault.

suppose:

```
// find a post and manage it
Post managedPost = em.find(postId); 

// get a random comment - the first one
Comment comment = managedPost.getCommentList().iterator().next();

// unlink the comment from the post
managedPost.getCommentList().remove(comment);

// remove the comment from the db
em.remove(comment);

// do other things
....

// do an useless merge on a already managed post
em.merge(managedPost);
```

the provider will cache statements (just a concept, don't take them as real):

1. `select post ...` for `em.find(postId)`
2. `delete from comment ...` for `managedPost.getCommentList().remove(comment)`
3. another `delete from comment ...` for `em.remove(comment)` (ignored as duplicate)
4. `update post ...` and `update comment ...` for the last `em.merge(managedPost)` (cascading to comments)

So, the last statement will re-insert the deleted comment.

You have to make sure to either `em.flush()` after the delete or remove cascade.